# Keeping cassandra table projections in sync on update

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm working on a service which uses Cassandra as a data store. I'm currently implementing Stop service which will contain list of Stops (transportation stops where passengers can board to the vehicle, e.g. Bus).

I need to support following scenarios:

1. Get stop by id
2. Get all stops by company id and agency id sorted by code asc, name asc

Here is how I implemented my tables to support that:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops(
    id                        uuid,
    client_id                 uuid,
    agency_id                 uuid,
    code                      varchar,
    name                      varchar,
    latitude                  double,
    longitude                 double,
    is_wheelchair_accessible  boolean, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops_by_client_id(
    client_id                 uuid,
    agency_id                 uuid,
    code                      varchar,
    name                      varchar,
    id                        uuid,
    latitude                  double,
    longitude                 double,
    is_wheelchair_accessible  boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((client_id, agency_id), code, name, id)
);
```

**Problem:**

This works well when I'm inserting the data and reading it. The problem occurs when I need to update one stop:

1. Update stop and set new code, name, latitude, longitude etc.
2. Update on `stops` table is not a problem, but I failed to apply the same change on `stops_by_client_id` projection.

What I tried so far:

1. I tried to update the row by client_id, agency_id and id, but it requires to pass all primary key values (client_id, agency_id, code, name, id) but in my `StopUpdated` event (on which I trigger the update) I don't have a previous values for code and name which I could use to construct such a query.
2. I tried to delete the row first, then insert the new (to simulate the update) but it fails for the same reason as 1.
3. I tried to construct primary key as follows `PRIMARY KEY ((client_id, agency_id, id), code, name)` but this would put every row in it's own partition which would make select query very inefficient.
4. I can't use materialized views because I'll need secondary index for some fields (e.g. code, is_wheelchair_accessible) so I can filter them.

Any ideas on how to solve this scenario?

Comment: A table can have both materialized views and secondary indexes, so 4) would still be an option.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I changed my architecture and modified `StopUpdate` event to contain old and new state (before and after the update). That way I have all needed info to assemble the query.

Answer (score 0):

Get the existing values of client_id and agency_id and other composite keys for the row you are going to update using id and use those values to delete the row in `stops_by_client_id` .

After updating that row in `stops` table, you have to get the values for other columns for that ID from the table and create a new row in `stops_by_client_id` table.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That would work when updates to those tables are synchronous, but in my case updates to those tables are done in async way as processors which writes to them receives asynchronous events (StopUpdated). I forgot to mention that in my question. Thanks @b1k for help.